# Drupal 7 Template Suggestions -- Why is this not working?

Tags: drupal, themes, preprocessor, drupal-7, theming

I've created my own theme. In the template.php file, I have the following code:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if(isset($variables['node'])){
        if($variables['node']->type === 'sports'){
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__sports';
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a page_*node*_sports.tpl.php file in my theme's template directory, and I have cleared the cache. However, the page_*node*_sports.tpl.php template doesn't get used. Doing some debugging, I stuck an echo statement at the beginning of the preprocess_page function, and that did appear onscreen, so I know the function is running. But the template suggestion just isn't working. I even removed the if statements inside the function, leaving just the $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = ... line, but still nada.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Although the template name in the line:

`$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__sports';`

should have underscores, the actual .tpl.php file should have hyphens instead.

Answer (score 2):

Have you also added a page.tpl.php to your theme folder? Suggestions only work if the original template exists too.

See also http://adaptivethemes.com/page-template-suggestions-per-node-type

Comment: Yes, I've got a page.tpl.php file there.

Comment: And I took a look at the link you posted and copied in it's D7 version directly, but still no luck.